# Identifying all the 1s in a sea of 0s

Tags: combinatorics, estimation, hypothesis-testing

I have an $N$-length binary string, the total number of 1s in the string is D.  Assume  N is much larger than D. Also, D is fairly larger than 1. (For example, N=1000, D=40).

Now, my aim is to find all the 1s in this string with a minimal number of tests.

Could someone suggest any classical methods or existing algorithms addressing such problems?

**What constitutes a test:**

Tests can be observing the output of a binary operation on a set of bits in the string. (Eg: XOR of randomly picked 5 bits, Boolean sum( OR) of 3 bit sets...)

I would also like to know what are the best method if my test only constitutes finding if any of the digits in a chosen set of digits is 1.

Comment: What kinds of "test" are allowed?

Comment: If the $1$s are uniformly distributed, I doubt you can do any better than checking each bit one by one.

Comment: Do you want to *actually find the places of* all the 1s or are you OK w just want to *estimate* the number of 1s?

Comment: Is checking whether a string contains only zeros one test? That would suggest repeatedly splitting a nonzero string and checking its two parts.

Comment: ...or checking the *total number* $k$ (i.e., *sum*) of $1$s in a substring another test?  If so, then split each substring into $k+1$ substrings and iterate...

Comment: In most programming languages it is probably faster to check bytes rather than individual bits.  Then when you find a non-zero byte, you  can check its bits one by one.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen

I added to the question the type of tests I am considering.

Comment: @timtfj Tests are typically any binary operation on a set of bits in the string. I have added details to the question.

Comment: @Jam There is no underlying probability distribution. It is a combinatorial scenario.

Comment: If each test can only reveal 1 bit of information, it seems like it is impossible to do better than $D$ tests and, without knowing $D$, would require $N$ tests.  If $D=1$, then a binary search seems optimal, which is $O(\log N)$.  Maybe there is an information-theoretic argument to at least get a similar kind of lower bound for general $D$, though the bound may not be optimal?

Comment: So you could, say, check whether a string of bits equalled $000000000000$ to tell whether it contained any $1$'s?

Comment: @timtfj yes. Thats correct